# In calculating entropy, why can the partitioning of an ensemble into microstates be chosen "somewhat arbitrarily"?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I'm confused by statistical entropy. It seems to me like the number of microstates for a given macrostate would increase without bound as finer partitionings of the phase space are chosen. Why is it that, as the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble#Precise_expressions_for_the_ensemble) states, "the size of the microstates in phase space can be chosen somewhat arbitrarily"? Is there an intuitive explanation for this? It must have something to do with the requirement that total energy is held constant, right?

I'm not trying to become a statistical physicist here, I'd just like to understand entropy better. Keep it simple, please! (I do have a mathematical background, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is essentially the same problem as trying to define [information entropy for a continuous probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy). You end up with an entropy value that has an offset depending on what units you chose for your random quantity. It is unfortunate, but the problem really stems from the fact that the number of possible physical states is uncountably infinite in classical mechanics, and so there is really no satisfactory unique definition of "a microstate". All we can do is to choose a typical size unit for phase space, and work with that.

Fortunately, the offset in entropy cannot actually be measured, and so we can comfortably live with this ambiguity. These sorts of arbitrary offsets appear from time to time in physics (e.g., choice of the zero of energy, electromagnetic gauge freedom, quantum phase freedom) and so I guess we just have to live with them.

Now, the really interesting question is this (and perhaps this is what you mean me to answer): why should entropy be defined by partitioning phase space into *equal-sized* units? In other words, why does it have to be equal units in *canonical* phase space? If I take my probability distribution in canonical phase space, and transform it via an arbitrary change of variables, then the differential information entropy computation would yield a different value. This is a general problem for the differential information entropy. However in classical mechanics we can give good reasons why this measure (Gibbs entropy) is the one that deserves the title of *the entropy*:

- The Gibbs entropy is a canonical invariant: If I perform [change of canonical basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (using a new set of canonical Hamiltonian coordinates) and compute my entropy in this new basis, *the entropy is the same*. This is very good, since a meaningful quantity should not depend on how we chose to write down the system's coordinates!
- Any loss of information about the system increases the Gibbs entropy irreversibly. (sounds like 2nd law of thermodynamics, no?)
- Moreover, the Gibbs entropy cannot decrease spontaneously since it is conserved by deterministic dynamics: Liouville's equation, which governs the motion of an ensemble of Hamiltonian systems, exactly conserves the Gibbs entropy. (hmm, even more like 2nd law of thermodynamics...)
- And, most importantly, the changes in Gibbs entropy in a thermodynamic system (canonical ensemble) correspond quantitatively to the changes in thermodynamic entropy that we measure in reality.

The Gibbs entropy is almost unique in having all these properties. It is not entirely unique since there are multiple Gibbs entropies (obtained by choosing different characteristic unit of phase space) in classical mechanics. In quantum mechanics it is even one step better: we have all the properties above, and there is no ambiguity about unit of phase space.

Sorry for the long answer, but hopefully it is simple enough as I didn't just throw a bunch of equations at you. :-)

(disclaimer: I have lately been heavily editing the wikipedia article you linked to, so don't count me as an independent source.)

Comment: +1 Most succinct. The [Jaynes paper "Information Theory and Statistical Mechanics"](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf) fleshes these ideas out a bit more.